# Unable to upload files

Tags: templates, assets, control-panel

I need to get images added to a team page, however there is no error message showing, when viewing images that are in the library, they are showing as checkered boxes (checkered wallpaper). Not exactly where to go to resolve this issue.

now I see this error
"There was an error uploading your file: Your upload directory isn’t writable"
I am logged in as superadmin
drwxr-xr-x  7 exp_eng pg8693376 4096 Jan  6  2015 assets

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked the file permissions for the folder the images are in?  They should be set to 777 as per the installation instructions... ([EE2](https://docs.expressionengine.com/v2/installation/installation.html) / [EE3](https://docs.expressionengine.com/latest/installation/installation.html))

Comment: What folder does Assets store the images? As I don't see anything that is designated?

Comment: Have you defined a file upload path for images?  Assets picks up on your settings for File Upload (from where you can also limit who can write files to the folder via "Restrict file uploading to select member groups").  To be honest the error sounds 100% like a permissions problem - so my hunch is that the directory you are checking permissions on is not the one that Assets is trying to upload to.  One possible solution (if you have any file at all showing within Assets) is simply to search for this file within your site, and check that it is in the folder you think Assets are going to...

Answer (score 0):

Another quick and simple first thing to check: make sure the file upload path to that upload folder is set correctly.

https://docs.expressionengine.com/latest/cp/files/uploads/form.html#upload-path

Comment: assets folder as well as the images folder is set to 777 and not working

Comment: OK, double check the file upload path (mentioned in my answer above).

Comment: the entire path to the "Assets" directory is 777 and it is not working.